# Should you say HaGomel after a flight?

Tags: blessing, travel, hagomel

Should someone say the HaGomel blessing after taking an airplane flight? I seem to remember this being the practice, but honestly the average commercial airplane flight these days is 10 times safer than driving to the supermarket...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are various Halachic opinions on this subject. [This article](http://dvar.info/pdf/Birchas%20Ha-gomel.pdf) by Rabbi Doniel Neustadt (pg. 3-4) sums up the various opinions very nicely (see footnotes there for names):

> 1) It is doubtful whether *ha-gomel* may be recited, unless a potentially dangerous situation developed during the flight.
>
> 2) *Ha-gomel* is recited only when the airplane crossed over an ocean or a desert.
>
> 3) *Ha-gomel* is recited after every airplane trip.

He then goes on to say that the general custom today follows #2 above.

I also saw that R' Moshe Feinstein zt"l held that one should only say Hagomel on the return trip (if the trip is less than 30 days). The exception to this is if one is traveling **to** visit Israel, where Ha-gomel should be said after both directions (i.e. after landing in Israel, and then after landing back in America). (taken from [here](http://www.cckollel.org/2005/parsha/current.pdf) pg. 2-3)

For a practical decision, please see a Rabbi.

Answer (score 9):

[R. Moshe Feinstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe_Feinstein) points out a fundamental difference between flying and driving. Flying is inherently dangerous. This is because man cannot survive in the air without the protection of the airplane. Therefore, because it is possible for the airplane's protection to fail it is considered a "dangerous situation". This is likened to the Talmud's case of crossing the ocean. There, too, it is inherently dangerous because man cannot survive at sea without the protection of the boat. Because it is possible for the boat's protection to fail it is therefore considered a "dangerous situation". Thus, flying gets a blessing because it parallel's the Talmud's case where a blessing is required.

Driving, on the other hand, is not inherently dangerous. That is to say that man can perfectly survive on land with or without the protection of the automobile. Thus it is not that the automobile is providing the necessary protection from a dangerous situation. The danger of automobile travel is external to the setting (e.g. a crash). Even though this is more dangerous in terms of likelihood for a fatal incident, the blessing is not based on likelihood of fatality but on inherentness of the danger.

The reason why it works this way is that the blessing is said as a thanks to God for allowing the protection to protect you from the inherent danger. Even if there is only a small likelihood of the protection failing, it still requires thanks. When it comes to a regular drive, though, there was no protection that God allowed to work, because there was never a danger to be protected from. If, however, something would happen on the drive, in which you were saved (e.g. if you survived a car crash) then that would be something to thank God for.

Thus, flying parallels the Talmud's case of inherent danger while driving does not, and this explains why a blessing would be made for flying and not driving.

**[Igros Moshe O.C. 2:59](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=918&st=&pgnum=251&hilite=)**

> הנה בדבר הנסיעה בעראפלאן אם צריך לברך הגומל כשהיה ביום שקט ובלא שום
>   חסרון בהמכונה ולא אירע שום דבר בדרך הוא ברור לע"ד שצריך לברך לא מבעיא
>   להסוברים בסימן רי"ט סעיף ט' דהני ארבעה דחשיב בברכות דף נ"ד לאו דוקא
>   שכן סברי רוב האחרונים וכן נוהגין כדאיתא במג"א סק"י ובט"ז סק"ז כתב שכן
>   מסתבר שודאי יש לברך דלא עדיפי מיורדי הים באניות לענין שכיחות הסכנה אלא
>   אף להסוברים בסעיף ט' דדוקא הני ארבעה נמי יש לברך מתרי טעמי חדא דהוא
>   ממש כספינה דהוא נמי אינו הולך על הארץ דזהו עיקר חלוק ספינה מדרכים
>   דיבשה דהדרכים דיבשה אין עצם הליכה חלוק מישיבתו בבית שאם לא יארע כלום
>   הרי לא היה שייך לחוש לכלום אבל בספינה שהוא על המים הרי עצם ההליכה הוא
>   ענין סכנה שצריך לינצל ממנה דהא במים א"א לחיות אלא זמן משהו בלא הצלתו
>   מהמים ע"י שנמצא בספינה ולכן כיון שאירע לפעמים שמתקלקלת הספינה ונמצא
>   שאין ההצלה ברורה צריך להודות ולברך הגומל וא"כ כ"ש בעראפלאן שגרוע ממים
>   שאף רגע אחד אין יכול להיות באויר שודאי שישיבתו בעראפלאן הוא הצלה וכיון
>   שאירע לפעמים שמתקלקל העראפלאן הרי נמי נמצא שאין ההצלה ברורה שלכן יש לו
>   להודות בברכת הגומל
>
> וזהו הטעם שאף בנסיעות הספינות שבזמננו נמי מברכין אף שנגד הספינות
>   דבזמן הגמ' ואף בזמן הש"ע הוטבו לענין סכנה בהרבה מאד שרק לפעמים רחוקות
>   טובא אירע טביעה בספינה ואולי הוא פחות מסתם דרכים שבזמנם שהיו בחזקת
>   סכנה שהוא משום דכיון דהספינה שיושב בה נחשבה שניצול על ידה מהסכנה שהוא
>   במים שנמצא שאף בספינות שלנו הוא נחשב ניצול מהסכנה והרי שייך בעצם לברך
>   רק אם היה ודאי בלא שום ספק שבספינה ניצולים מהמים היה פטור משום שלא היה
>   שייך להחשיב שנעשה לו חסד מהשי"ת בנסיעה זו אבל כיון שאף בספינות אלו
>   שבזמננו אינה הצלה ברורה אף שרק לפעמים רחוקות אירע טביעה שלא מצלת נחשב
>   עכ"פ שנעשה לו חסד מהשי"ת שיש לברך ואף שהוא חסד קטן מכפי שהיה בימים ההם
>   נמי צריך לברך דכי על חסד קטן לא נודה להשי"ת שעשה עמנו החסד והא חזינן
>   לגבי חיוב ברכה על עניני אכילה ושתיה והנאה שאין חלוק בין אכילה ושתיה
>   והנאה גדולה לאכילה ושתיה והנאה מועטת ול"ד להולכי סתם דרכים שבעצם אין
>   בזה סכנה ואין צורך להצלה ורק כשאירע איזה דבר כליסטים וכדומה צריכים
>   להצלה אבל כיון שלא אירע שלא היה שם שום דבר המזיק הרי נתברר שלא היה שם
>   שום חשש סכנה ולא נעשה עמו יותר חסד מכפי שהיה בביתו ולכן אף שעתה
>   במדינתנו נוסעים במאשינעס שיותר מצוי חשש סכנה נמי א"צ לברך אלא כשאירע
>   ח"ו איזה דבר שפגעו ונגעו המאשינעס ולא הוזקו אבל כשהיה כשורה שלא נפגע
>   במאשין אחר הרי נתברר שלא היה חשש סכנה ולא נעשה עמו יותר חסד מאם היה
>   בביתו

Comment: +1 obviously an essential source to bring to the table, and a nice summary too. On the other hand, does anyone know of anyone who actually follows this ruling? I don't think I've ever seen it followed

Comment: @DoubleAA Fair point. I actually wasn't posting it as much for the final halachic ruling, as for the sevara to explain why flying could be more of a reason to bless than driving even though it is less dangerous. I think that was a key part of the question here (and it was the entire question of the post that was closed as a duplicate of this that led me here).

Answer (score 8):

The basic rule is to say *hagomel* after crossing an ocean (on water) or a desert (on land) but not after other trips.

http://www.mevaseret.org/mmy/searchshiurim.php?shiur=105 lists various rabbis' views regarding airplane travel. I haven't checked the sources it cites, but if it's to be trusted then Rabbi Sternbuch cites others as saying not to say it unless the flight was "eventful" [whatever that means], the *Tzitz Eliezer* says to say *hagomel* after any but a short domestic flight, and Rabbi *Moshe* Feinstein says to say it after any flight.

As always, for practical guidance, [CYLOR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CYLOR).

**Update:** I've checked the sources of that Web page, but have skimmed them rather than read every word. (That's always dangerous, but) AFAICT [the *Tzitz Eliezer*](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14510&st=&pgnum=48&hilite=) actually says to say *hagomel* after going over a desert or ocean [*yam*, which may include larger seas or what-have-you], unless it's a short domestic flight. I don't see that he says to say *hagomel* after a long flight that doesn't go over a *yam* or desert, which is what the Web page implies in his name. [*Rav Moshe* Feinstein](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=918&st=&pgnum=251&hilite=) is quoted correctly AFAICT. [*Rav Moshe* Sternbuch](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20025&st=&pgnum=143&hilite=) is quoted incompletely. He actually writes that the custom in South Africa is to say *hagomel* after any flight over the *yam* [or, I suppose, the desert?]; he also quotes [the *Chazon Ish*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avrohom_Yeshaya_Karelitz) second-hand as saying to say *hagomel* after any flight, and others ([the *Belzer rav*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aharon_Rokeach), [the *Tchubiner rav*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dov_Berish_Weidenfeld)) secondhand as saying not to say it.